# In Keras, is there documentation describing the string name to class mappings for initializers, optimizers, etc?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Is there any documentation describing what string names map to what objects in Keras? For example, below I create an Embedding layer from `tf.keras.layers` and I can use `'uniform'` to map to the `tf.keras.initializers.RandomUniform` class.

```
tf.keras.layers.Embedding(1000, 64, embeddings_initializer='uniform')
```

But I only know that by seeing examples of that usage. I presume the supported string forms are documented somewhere, but I can't seem to find such documentation, and digging through the code got too abstract to follow easily.

Version: TF 1.13.1

Comment: I am afraid not

Comment: Or, second best, does someone know where in the code to look this up?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no list of string constants available in keras implementation in TF (and, I suppose, in original keras neither).

For the [initializer](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.13/tensorflow/python/keras/initializers.py) case the `'uniform'` string is converted to config and a fabric method is called on that config with a hint to create an object from initializers namespace (can be found here as [def deserialize_keras_object](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.13/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py)):

```
config = {'class_name': str(identifier), 'config': {}}

deserialize_keras_object(
      config,
      module_objects=globals(),
      custom_objects=custom_objects,
      printable_module_name='initializer')
```

Therefore, I can not think of a better way to, for example, list all initializers than:

```
import tensorflow as tf

for k, v in tf.keras.initializers.__dict__.items():
    if not k[0].isupper() and not k[0] == "_":
        print(k)
```

And output, although with extra values, is like:

```
constant
glorot_normal
glorot_uniform
identity
ones
orthogonal
zeros
he_normal
he_uniform
lecun_normal
lecun_uniform
normal
random_normal
random_uniform
uniform
truncated_normal
deserialize
get
serialize
```

Comment: Plus, the reason why it is being done is by using a mapping in the above way is that it needs to be bounded in a local thread context and if we have a reference to an initializer class, which is being used twice or thrice in a deep neural network, the newbies may make mistakes regarding assigning/changing the reference with a new set of parameter, thereby rendering the initial assigned distribution useless

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/initializers/__init__.py#L138-L146