# How can I find the list of available string abbreviations for keras classes used as arguments?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

Keras (specifically I'm using tf.keras) allows you to use certain strings as arguments when creating a new class instance, and these strings reference other Keras classes. For example, 'elu' in `tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='elu')` is a shortcut for `tf.keras.activations.elu`.

However, in the documentation, I can't seem to find any sort of comprehensive list of valid arguments for each parameter. Some are going to be obvious, but it would be a lot easier if I had a list to work from. Furthermore, the behavior of arguments like 'accuracy' in `model.compile(..., metrics=['accuracy'])` seems far too ambiguous to be lacking in documentation describing its behavior.

Can anyone help to point me to appropriate resources for this issue? In addition to the above mentioned 'accuracy', I'm also particularly interested in the monitor parameter of `tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping`. And does anyone know why the source documentation is lacking so much? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sadly, this is not documented and there is no single place storage of such string constants.

When keras receives `tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='elu')` it will go into the activation function module and will literally call activation function by its name if it is present there. So, `activation='elu'` will be converted into  `tf.keras.activations.elu()`.

At the same time, it means that you can use any activation function name as a string.

You can take a look at the code [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56176475/in-keras-is-there-documentation-describing-the-string-name-to-class-mappings-fo/56179296#56179296) to workaround this problem.

Comment: Thank you sir, it's really a shame that their documentation is lacking so much

Answer (score 4):

This code snippet would do

```py
for k, v in tf.keras.activations.__dict__.items():
    if not k[0].isupper() and not k[0] == "_":
        print(k)
```

```
deserialize
elu
exponential
gelu
get
hard_sigmoid
linear
relu
selu
serialize
sigmoid
softmax
softplus
softsign
swish
tanh
```

Comment: This includes deserialize, get, and serialize methods which are not activation functions